# TO CHECK THE DATE FORMAT IN TABLE USING IF CONDITION

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

I need to check whether the dates in a table are in the format of DD-MON-YYYY and if it is not then need to raise exception ..Please help me as i am new to this field.

Comment: the date column is varchar2 or date ?

Comment: Why an `if` condition specifically? Why can't you use SQL? Also, a definition of the column and sample data would help a lot.

Comment: Also, why the [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html) application specifically?

Comment: Suggest me which else will be better for a beginner to learn oracle?@ William Robertson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
to_date(yourDateColumn,'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

assuming `yourDateColumn` is a string (`varchar2` or `char` or whatever). `to_date` will throw an exception if the date is not valid.

If you really need to use `if` then you could implement a function that will return `1` if the date is valid and `0` otherwise say:

```
function isValidDate(yourDate in varchar2) return number is 
 tempDate Date;  
begin 
  tempDate := to_date(yourDate,'DD-MON-YYYY');
  return 1;
exception when others then 
  return 0;
end;
```

And then use the function in `IF` statement

```
if isValidDate(yourDate in Date)=1 then 
--perform some operations 
end if;
```

However, keep in mind that it is a bad practice to store dates as a sting in a database.

Comment: In Oracle 12.2 you have a build-in function for that [VALIDATE_CONVERSION](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html#GUID-DC485EEB-CB6D-42EF-97AA-4487884CB2CD)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit  OK, good to know! However the OP (among other things) didn't mention Oracle version.

Comment: @Plirkee so we might as well assume a recent Oracle version.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Everything is possible. And yes, of course,   your contribution is valuable. On the other hand - not everybody has the latest version of Oracle.  I would assume that majority works with older versions...

Comment: As long as you mention that a new feature requires a particular version then I don't see a problem. (This is just a general comment by the way, not a criticism of your answer which I have upvoted.)

Comment: The date column for my requirement is varchar2 @ moudiz

Comment: as i need to write many checking conditions with  exception i prefer ' if '..as i am new to this field i dont have much knowledge.suggest me if there is some other better solution.@ William Robertson

Comment: @Dharani.C it depends on what are you doing exactly, what is your oracle version etc. - you gave out little to no information at all. Does the above solution work for you?  If yes please up-vote and accept.